# Grunt copy directory from outside project root?

Tags: gruntjs, copy

I managed to copy something from the project to its parent directory but not the other way arround

```
/themes/next/less/STUFF <- from
/themes/sym/Gruntfile.js
/themes/sym/target2/STUFF <- to (keep folder structure of source)

copy: {
  fonts: {
    cwd: '..',
    expand: true,
    src: './next/less/**',
    dest: './target2/'
  }
},
```

I managed to copy STUFF but this way its creates a `next` folder inside `target2` ... I do not want that.

What I want is simply like I would do this from the root `sym` directory

`cp -R ../next/less/. target2`

I tryed with `.` as cwd and have it actually totally ignore the `dest` and place the `next` folder right into the root.

Answer (score 0):

To flatten all the files to a single folder, use `flatten: true` together with `filter:'isFile'`

```
copy: {
  fonts: {
    cwd: '..',
    expand: true,
    flatten: true,
    src: './next/less/**',
    dest: './target2/STUFF'
    filter: 'isFile'
  }
}
```

Ref [Flattening the filepath output @ github.com/grunt-contrib-copy](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy)

Comment: To 'flatten' refers to abandoning the folder structure form the source directory and put everything into one directory right? I do not what that! And I have no idea why you think I do. As I said what i want is `cp -R ../next/less/. target2` in Grunt.